# Generate unique id for a new item in models on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I populate book items into my Book model,

But I found there are many items have the same id.

So, how to create unique id for items. To prevent many items from having the same id ?

Here is the book model code

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :isbn ,:price ,:comment ,:author ,:sale_type ,:publisher ,:sn ,:category
   attr_accessible :location, :category, :release_date
   validates_uniqueness_of :sn
```

Here are the part of my items

```
irb(main):058:0> Book.all[1..10]
+-----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| id  | pric | com | cre | upda | rele | loc | sn   | isb | aut | sale | name | cat | publ |
+-----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| 118 | 4543 | 作  | 201 | 2013 | 2006 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 趙  | prom | 求索 | 商  | 聯經 |
| 118 | 872  | 馬  | 201 | 2013 | 2013 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 黎  | prom | 告別 | 政  | 聯經 |
| 118 | 2105 | 某  | 201 | 2013 | 2012 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 吳  | prom | 複眼 | 政  | 夏日 |
| 118 | 301  | 作  | 201 | 2013 | 2006 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 王  | norm | 天香 | 歷  | 麥田 |
| 118 | 411  | 少  | 201 | 2013 | 2008 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 韓  | norm | 鞋癖 | 商  | 聯經 |
| 119 | 3751 | 有  | 201 | 2013 | 2010 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 紀  | prom | 私家 | 體  | 印刻 |
| 119 | 3361 | 文  | 201 | 2013 | 2010 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 林  | fix_ | 我不 | 體  | 印刻 |
| 119 | 1140 | 何  | 201 | 2013 | 2012 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 邁  | norm | 正義 | 體  | 雅言 |
| 119 | 888  | 一  | 201 | 2013 | 2007 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 福  | fix_ | 生命 | 商  | 究竟 |
| 119 | 3283 | 近  | 201 | 2013 | 2011 | --- | 2124 | 978 | 芮  | norm | 海拉 | 政  | 遠流 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----+------+-----+-----+------+------+-----+------+
```

here the rake code to generate my data

```
 16         bk = Book.new(:sn => real_sn,:name => book_name, :isbn=>isbn,
 17                      :price =>Random.rand(200..5000), :location=>location, :category=>["商業","歷史","體育","政治"].sample,
 18                      :author => author, :sale_type => [:fix_priced, :normal, :promotion].sample, :publisher => publisher,
 19                      :release_date => rand(10.years).ago, :comment => comment
 20                      )
```

Columns in the table I use the Postgre DB

```
    Column    |            Type             |                     Modifiers
--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                     | not null default nextval('books_id_seq'::regclass)
 price        | integer                     |
 comment      | text                        |
 created_at   | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at   | timestamp without time zone | not null
 release_date | text                        |
 location     | text                        |
 sn           | bigint                      |
 isbn         | bigint                      |
 author       | text                        |
 sale_type    | text                        |
 name         | text                        |
 category     | text                        |
 publisher    | text                        |
Indexes:
    "books_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: can you show the mysql result of `desc book`

Comment: I use the postgre not Mysql.

Comment: id field by default is an auto incrementing unique primary key. I think you have specified it to be something else. Probably your migration is wrong. Id field should not be specified there.

Comment: ok, post the migration file that created book table

Comment: I added the additional information

Comment: primary_key is books_pkey instead of id, so I would recommend sticking to Rails conventions and using id as a primary key.

Comment: use a postgres uuid field

Comment: excuse me i don't know what is books_pkey , I didn't set up it. How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

The code above, does not save any record in the database, it just **instantiate** objects of Book model. You should either save the object after initialization `bk.save` or use the **create** method instead of new.

```
  bk = Book.new(:sn => real_sn,:name => book_name, :isbn=>isbn,
                :price =>Random.rand(200..5000), :location=>location,
                :category=>["商業","歷史","體育","政治"].sample, :author => author,
                :sale_type => [:fix_priced, :normal, :promotion].sample,
                :publisher => publisher, :release_date => rand(10.years).ago,
                :comment => comment)
  bk.save
```

Or alternatively you can use the create method

```
  bk = Book.create(:sn => real_sn,:name => book_name, :isbn=>isbn,
                :price =>Random.rand(200..5000), :location=>location,
                :category=>["商業","歷史","體育","政治"].sample, :author => author,
                :sale_type => [:fix_priced, :normal, :promotion].sample,
                :publisher => publisher, :release_date => rand(10.years).ago,
                :comment => comment)
```

Once saved in the database, it will automatically gain a unique id.